# Displaying Image in QmessageBox

Tags: c++, qt, messagebox

How can I display an image in a message box. I tried

```
about.setIcon(":/pics/goku3.jpg");
```

but it gives me errors. I know I can use the built-in about box. Here is the full code for displaying this about box.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionUmer_s_Program_triggered()
{
    QMessageBox about;

    about.setText("Umer's Program");
    about.setInformativeText("Copyright ; 2012 Umer Software Inc.\nI wrote this program     for fun.\n);
    about.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    about.setIcon(":/pics/goku3.jpg");   // here is the error
    about.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
    about.show();
    about.exec();
}
```

Please also tell me how can set the size of that image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not use `about.setIcon(":/pics/goku3.jpg");` because the `QMessageBox::setIcon(Icon)` method only works with predefined icons that are

```
QMessageBox::NoIcon
QMessageBox::Question
QMessageBox::Information
QMessageBox::Warning
QMessageBox::Critical
```

To load your own picture your should use:

```
void setIconPixmap ( const QPixmap & pixmap )
```

For example:

```
about.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/pics/goku3.jpg"));
```

Also, if you want to use this format `":/pics/goku3.jpg"`  make sure your have your `.qrc` file (this is a resource file) configured correctly.

More information you can get from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html).

Comment: best way to resize the image itself
but if you wanna do it from code then create a new pixmap 
QPixmap myPixmap(30,30);  ( the size ) 
and then  load the image : 
myPixmap.load(filename);
more info here  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#pixmap-information